# Too many input parameters error from class method

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I have writen a class in MATLAB like below:

```
classdef sizeInfo
properties
end

methods
    function [row column] = getSize(m)
        [row column] = size(m); 
    end
end
end
```

When I make use of this class's `getSize` function, it always reports a error like below:

```
s=sizeInfo
[r c]=s.getSize(data)
Error using sizeInfo/getSize
Too many input arguments.
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: What is `data`? What do you get if you input a scalar?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of a class function is always a reference to the object itself, thus `function [row column] = getSize(m)` was a function without parameters and m the implicit passed reference.

```
classdef sizeInfo
properties
end

methods
    function [row column] = getSize(obj,m)
        [row column] = size(m); 
    end
end
end
```

One advice: Read the documentation carefully. After learning Java, c++ and python I expected to understand oop. Matlab surprises me again and again.

Comment: +1, but why the complaint? Passing the reference to self is no different from how Python does it...?

Comment: I'm not complaining about this behaviour, but ever tried to implement a singleton pattern which is not broken by `evalin('base','clear all')`, without using java? Sometimes it is nearly impossible to debug why your code does not work in a costumer environment.

Comment: It's more readable to define it as a static method

Comment: Generally I avoid singletons -- there is almost always a better alternative (see the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)). And remember: "Try to build a system that even a fool can use, and only fools will use it." :)

Answer (score 1):

For this definition of `getSize` (which does not need access to an instance of the class) you should define it as [`Static`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html):

```
methods(Static)
    function [row column] = getSize(m)
        [row column] = size(m); 
    end
end
```